# Getting "NameError: name 'room_path' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

Here is the code that I am having issues with. I am using the Python 3.6.

```
def room():
    room_path=["1","2"]
    user_choice = ""

print ("If you decide to ditch Todd and go to the campfire alone, enter 1")
print ("If you decide to drag Todd with you to the campfire, enter 2")
user_choice = input("your option number")

if user_choice == room_path [1]:
    print ("yes")
elif user_choice == room_path [2]:
    print ("no")
```

When I run the code and enter in a number, here is the error I get:

```
    if user_choice == room_path [1]:
NameError: name 'room_path' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because the name `room_path` is declared within the scope of the
`room` function and therefore cannot be called from outside that function.

Here is a nice link the explains the scope of variables in Python:

http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html

To fix the problem you could declare `room_path` outside of your `room` function, which you probably also want to do with `user_choice` and remove the `room` function altogether.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
room_path=["1","2"]
user_choice = ""

print ("If you decide to ditch Todd and go to the campfire alone, enter 1")
print ("If you decide to drag Todd with you to the campfire, enter 2")
user_choice = input("your option number")

if user_choice == room_path [1]:
    print ("yes")
elif user_choice == room_path [2]:
    print ("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit issue I think,

```
room_path=["1","2"]
```

it defines `str` for `room_path` list

but when you input `str` is: `1` or `2` should be matched

```
if user_choice == room_path [0]:
```

with `[0]` is the first column of `room_path` list.

Answer (score 0):

Error occur because you had define `room_path` variable in method and access and used `room_path` variable outside the method.

```
def room():
    room_path=["1","2"]
    user_choice = ""

    print ("If you decide to ditch Todd and go to the campfire alone, enter 1")  
    print ("If you decide to drag Todd with you to the campfire, enter 2")
    user_choice = input("your option number")

    if user_choice == room_path [1]:
        print ("yes")
    elif user_choice == room_path [2]:
        print ("no")
```